# What do "muckraker" and "rake muck" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

Are they the same? What do they mean?

Here is the sentence:

> I was one of the most experienced. All of us were judged by our ability to **rake muck**. The head **muckraker** was Frederica Jansz...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One who investigates and exposes issues of corruption that often violate widely held values.

Comment: thanks you. @Jen please pay attention to @UserID: he understood the question and provided a clear definition.  +1

Comment: That's a hugely tendentious definition!  Did coverage of the former governor of California or the two former governors of New York -- "muckraking" in almost anyone's vocabulary -- "expose issues of corruption"?